# Watir "Element is no longer attached to the DOM" error

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I'm having an issue with a test that I've created where I will randomly get this issue, from what I understand it's because there is java script running that is periodically refreshing the element. I'm unsure of how I can stop this error from happening, here is my code for the test;

EDIT: As advised I've removed the elements from variables and are calling them directly, but the error remains, here is my updated code and error message (including line numbers)

```
47 When(/^I click the create room button$/) do

  49 Watir::Wait.for_condition(10, 2, "Waiting for room data to load") {
    50 @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').div(:id, 'room_list').present?
  51 }

  53 rooms = []

  55 @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').div(:id, 'room_list').as.each do |room |
    56 rooms << room.attribute_value('data-room-id')
  57 end

  59 puts roomvalue = rooms.size.to_i

  61 @current_rooms = rooms

  63 roomvalue

  65 Watir::Wait.for_condition(10, 2, "Waiting for button to be present") {
    66 @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id, 'create_room_form_button').present?
  67 }
  68 @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id, 'create_room_form_button').click
69 end
```

The error that I'm getting is;

```
Element is no longer attached to the DOM - {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x68d78665e583d27c id="{80a6296c-fc63-4d63-917c-9a2bf35bb429}">} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
  ./features/step_definitions/multiplayer_fe_steps.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/multiplayer_fe_steps.rb:55:in `/^I click the create room button$/'
  features/multiplayer_fe.feature:21:in `When I click the create room button'
```

Thanks to steel for the answer provided, however even when the element is placed directly into the wait statement I get the same error, was there anything else that I can try to resolve the issue?

Edit: I've tried using a lamda for my list however, when I did, I would get a different error saying 'undefined method 'as' on my .as.each do |room |

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Watir that well, but I suspect the problem is that you're storing the reference in a variable. Maybe try this:

```
Watir::Wait.for_condition(10, 2, "Waiting for room data to load") {
  @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').present?
}
```

And also

```
Watir::Wait.for_condition(10, 2, "Waiting for button to be present") {
 @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id, 'create_room_form_button').present?
}
@browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id, 'create_room_form_button').click
```

The problem is that each time you call @browser.find_element... you're looking through the DOM afresh. When you store the variable, you aren't storing the procedure to find or not, you're storing the actual element, found or not. When you try to call a found element variable that is no longer there, you get this Selenium StaleObjectError.

Going out on another limb here, but you might also **try wrapping those calls** in a Proc or Lambda, instead of a variable.

```
createpress = -> { @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').button(:id, 'create_room_form_button') }
```

Then, when you want to trigger it, call it:

```
create_press.call.present?
```

That's pretty verbose and repetitive. If you ever head over to Capybara, you could try the Dill gem to wrap these elements up in widgets, which are like procs. https://github.com/mojotech/dill

Comment: Thanks to steel for the answer provided, however even when the element is placed directly into the wait statement I get the same error, was there anything else that I can try to resolve the issue?

Comment: If you udpate that code, I can take another look. Mind marking line 63, the error line, in your code as well? I also updated my answer with some more ideas, including addressing your second variable storing a reference, and why that's a bad pattern.

Comment: Thanks steel, I've updated my code and my error in the main post

Comment: Why are you using `as.each` ? Can you just use `.each` ?

Comment: I get a no method error using as.each or just .each

Comment: @Ethranes I think I'm out of suggestions, since I don't really know Watir that well. If I were in your shoes, I'd start throwing in `binding.pry`, assuming you've added and required the `pry` gem, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

`@browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').div(:id, 'room_list').as`

....is, at the moment you declare it, a static Array containing a list of link elements.

If, while you're iterating over that list of elements, the DOM updates, then those elements become stale. This is why you get that error.

As for how to solve your underlying problem of iterating over a list of updating link elements...

One thing you might do is get the size of the list, and then reference the links directly like this:

```
count = @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').div(:id, 'room_list').as

count.times do |x|
  rooms << @browser.iframe(:id, 'iconsole-plugin-session_iframe__').div(:id, 'lobby_rooms').div(:id, 'room_list').a(index: x-1).attribute_value('data-room-id')
end
```